# How to use windows hooking to get all objects of a WinForm?

Tags: c#, object, properties, hook

I'm developing a spy function for the automation testing tool. The spy function needs to get all objects and properties of the program that I want to spy. 
At this time, I can get all of the handles "Class names and captions" from the Wordpad and Notepad and print them to the console.

Now, I need to get objects and properties from what I got from those handles which is `classname` and `captions`. Here is the spying result from the console:

```
WordPadClass
Process Name:wordpad
Child handle:UIRibbonCommandBarDock UIRibbonDockLeft
Child handle:UIRibbonCommandBarDock UIRibbonDockRight
Child handle:UIRibbonCommandBarDock UIRibbonDockTop
Child handle:UIRibbonCommandBar Ribbon
Child handle:UIRibbonWorkPane Ribbon
Child handle:NUIPane
Child handle:NetUIHWND
Child handle:NetUICtrlNotifySink
Child handle:NetUICtrlNotifySink
Child handle:UIRibbonCommandBarDock UIRibbonDockBottom
Child handle:Afx:00000000FFAA0000:0:0000000000010003:0000000000000010:0000000000
000000
Child handle:msctls_statusbar32
Child handle:Afx:00000000FFAA0000:0
Child handle:Static Zoo&m
Child handle:Static 100%
Child handle:Button -
Child handle:msctls_trackbar32
Child handle:Button +
Child handle:AfxControlBar42u
Child handle:AfxControlBar42u
Child handle:AfxControlBar42u
Child handle:AfxControlBar42u
Child handle:Afx:00000000FFAA0000:0:0000000000010003:0000000000000010:0000000000
000000
Child handle:RICHEDIT50W
Child handle:UIRibbonWorkPane UIRibbonWorkPane
Press any key to continue . . .
```

1. "UIRibbonCommandBarDock" this is the classname
2. "UIRibbonDockLeft" this is the caption

Thank you for your help.